# nav bar not appearing at top of my page, appearing in weird place

Tags: html, css

1 
I was trying to create a model google site to practice my skills with html and css unfortunately im running into a weird problem where my navigation menu is appearing inside my image div, despite being created before that. I have added background to the navs and img container to make it easier to debug. Thanks for any help guys really appreciate. I posted a copy of my code on jfiddle, im trying to get the blue elements (nav) on top and cant figure out why they would be inside the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/thd2vh2b/1/4

Thanks for any help really appreciate it.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Google.ca </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>


nav {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-color: blue;
}


div {
background-color:yellow;
text-align:center;
padding-top:100px;
padding-bottom: 75px;
margin: auto;


}



nav ul li{
display:inline;
display:inline;
margin-right: 

}

#nav1 {

float:left;
display:inline;


}


#nav2 {
float:right;
display:inline;
margin:8px;

}
footer li {

float: left;
margin:8px;
display:inline;
}

#rightbar li{
float:right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
<nav id="nav1">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li> <a href="" >About</a></li>
<li> <a href="" >Store</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav id="nav2">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li> <a href="" >Gmail</a></li>
<li> <a href="" >Images</a></li>
<li> <a href="https://www.google.ca/intl/en/about/products/"><img src="gsquare.png" ></a></li>
<li><a href="https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464"> <img src="gbell.png" ></a></li>
<li><a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/"><li> <img src="user.png" ></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div>
<img src="logo.png";>
</div>
<footer id="rightbar";>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li><p>Privacy</p></li>
<li><p> Terms </p></li>
<li><p> Settings</p></li>
</ul>
</footer>
<footer>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li><p>Advertising</p></li>
<li><p> Business</p></li>
<li><p> Business</p></li>
</ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[Pic of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upwp6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is it correct? That's how you want it?**

```css
#divname {
background-color:yellow;
text-align:center;
padding-top:100px;
padding-bottom: 75px;
margin: auto;
}

div ul li{
display:inline;

margin-right: 10px;

}

#nav1 {



display:inline-block;
background-color:blue;


}


#nav2 {
float:right;
display:inline;
margin:8px;
background-color:blue;

}
footer li {

float: left;
margin:8px;
display:inline;

}

#rightbar li{
float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Google.ca </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StackQ.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav1">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li> <a href="" >About</a></li>
<li> <a href="" >Store</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="divname">
<div id="top">

<div id="nav2">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li> <a href="" >Gmail</a></li>
<li> <a href="" >Images</a></li>
<li> <a href="https://www.google.ca/intl/en/about/products/"><img src="gsquare.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464"> <img src="gbell.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/"> <img src="user.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="a">
<img src="logo.png">
</div>
</div>
<footer id="rightbar">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li><p>Privacy</p></li>
<li><p> Terms </p></li>
<li><p> Settings</p></li>
</ul>
</footer>
<footer>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li><p>Advertising</p></li>
<li><p> Business</p></li>
<li><p> Business</p></li>
</ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aproximately, I figured out from your code that the reason it wouldnt centre align is because my 2 nav bars were getting extra padding from the div they were in, which allowed them to over lap with my other div in the centre. Thanks